# .htaccess and browser caching

Tags: htaccess, cache

I ran across [these suggested htaccess edits](http://thomasgriffinmedia.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-in-wordpress-via-htaccess/). Is this a good practice? Is this something I should implement on my wordpress site?:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice, but no, it is not on topic here. BTW: It must be `access plus 1 year`, note the `plus`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely good practice. Having the browser cache pages and resources is a great way to speed up page loading as well as reduce bandwidth usage on your server.

I recommend checking out [Google's PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/) for more tips on how to improve the performance of your web pages.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is great practice.

I would also encourage you to checkout appcache. If you add one year to any file, it's good to make it browser-ready ([AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/))