# Proper caching method with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess and browser caching](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28606/htaccess-and-browser-caching)

There are a lot of snippets that enable caching on a website and I don't know which one should I use. The most popular is something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

I also found something similar, but with keyword 'plus'. Like this:

`ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"`

What does it mean, because I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Another snippet I found:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: Hmm, not sure why this was closed. It is similar but the OP is asking different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first snippet, you should avoid using the `ExpiresDefault` line as that will cache all your pages as well which you probably don't want.

The 'plus' keyword you mention is optional, see the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html#AltSyn) for details. So that snippet is the same as the first but with the expiry time in seconds, not days.

The final snippet is a different caching method, but which basically has the same result. Some resources suggest Cache-control is better than Expires, I think because it plays more friendly with proxies. I'm not sure why the line for Javascript sets it to private since that is equally as valid set to public.